# Processing Excel Data Using Pyexcel

Tags: python, excel, csv

Here's a Python question:

Hello I'm making a web app, its receives the data from a spreadsheet(.csv) turning them into integers from. Evaluating those values, returning those values and writing that data to the 4'th column of the sheet, for each row. As you can see in my code:

```
import fileinput
import csv
import pyexcel as pe
records = pe.iget_records(file_name="test.xlxs")






cho = raw_input("\nStart Forecaster on file?:<1/0>")

if cho == 1:

  for record in records:
     rem = record[i,0]
     sold1 = record[i,1]
     sold2 = record[i,2]

     rem = int(rem)
     sold1 = int(sold1)
     sold2 = int(sold2)
     result = forecast(rem,sold1,sold2)
     record[i,4] = result
  print "Forecast Complete! Please check the file!"


else:
  quit()  




def calculate(rem,sold1,sold2):

   result = ((l+t)/2)*3
   return result





def forecast(rem,sold1,sold2):

    if (rmn == 0 and sold1 == 0 and sold2 ==0): #All ZERO
          return 15
    elif (rmn == 0 and sold1 == 0 and sold2 < 10): #ALL FOR ONE PRODUCT VALUE
          return sold2*3
    elif (rmn == 0 and sold1 < 10 and sold2 ==0):
          return sold1*3
    elif (rmn < 10 and sold1 == 0 and sold2 == 0):
          return rmn*3
     #END FOR ONE PRODUCT VALUE
    elif (rmn>= 10 and  sold1>=10 and sold2>=10):

          if((rmn/3)>=(sold1+10) or (rmn/3)>=(sold1+10)):
              return 0
          else:
              return calculate(rmn,sold1,sold2)-rmn
    elif (rmn<10 and sold1<10 and sold2<10):
          return calculate(rmn,sold1,sold2)
    elif (rmn == 0 and sold1>=10 and sold2>=10):
          return calculate(rmn,sold1,sold2)
    else:
          return sold1
```

... There were no errors but it didnt have any effect on the csv file. Any ideas?  Also at  `print "Forecast Complete! Please check the file!"` .. when i run the program it doesn't get there which means there has to be something wrong with the looping? I'm figuring it out right now. But I want to ask for help as well.

Original file:

```
1  2  3
1  2  3
1  2  3
```

What I wanted to happen:

```
1  2  3  result(digits)
1  2  3  result(digits)
1  2  3  result(digits)
```

Comment: I don't use the library specifically, but it doesn't look like you're writing anything to the file anywhere. `records = pe.iget_records(file_name="test.xlxs")` is just pulling the file contents into Python, where you manipulate it and then throw the results away. Have a look at the [tutorial](https://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_file.html#update-an-existing-column-to-an-existing-file) on writing/saving changes.

Comment: I tried `records.save_as("test.xlsx")` but still it doesn't work, how do you see my loop? is there something wrong with it?

Comment: I don't have time to play with the library at the moment and no test data. However, you should verify with a `print` of the data before saving that you have actually calculated the things you think you have.

Comment: may i suggest the `pandas`,`openpyxl`,or `xlsxwriter` modules instead of `pyexcel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

**pyexcel.iget_records** returns a list of dictionary, and is suitable for data with a header row. 'records.save_as' will not work because the returned data structure is a standard Python list, which naturally not has save_as function.

**pyexcel.Sheet** instances would have a [save_as](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.5/generated/pyexcel.Sheet.save_as.html#pyexcel.Sheet.save_as) function, but 'pyexcel.get_sheet' should be used in your code. Or [pyexcel.save_as](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.5/generated/pyexcel.save_as.html#pyexcel.save_as), the module level function could save an array into a file. See [the example here](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.5/tutorial_data_conversion.html#how-to-save-an-python-array-as-an-excel-file).

## Sample solution

```
>>> import pyexcel as  p
>>> sheet = p.get_sheet(file_name='test.xlsx') # pip install pyexcel-xlsx
>>> sheet
Sheet 1:
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+
>>> for row in sheet:
...      print row
...
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> results = []
>>> for row in sheet:
...     results.append(sum(row)) # <- do your own forcast here
...
>>> results
[6, 6, 6]
>>> sheet.column += results
>>> sheet
Sheet 1:
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
+---+---+---+---+
>>> sheet.save_as('new.csv')
```

## Long answer

**pyexcel** helps you get python data structure in one liner. There are [4 functions](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.5/capability.html#four-data-access-functions): get_array, get_dict, get_records and get_book_dict. [Two streaming functions](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.5/capability.html#id2) are provided to handle bigger data size: iget_array and **iget_records**. It is assumed that the developer needs the data for analysis only.

**pyexcel** provides [two custom functions](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.5/capability.html#two-native-functions) to help you manipulate the data: **get_sheet** and get_book. The former one returns [pyexcel.Sheet](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.5/api.html#sheet) and the latter returns [pyexcel.Book](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.5/api.html#book). It is assumed that the developer needs to manipulate the rows, colums and sheets, then save the sheets/books back to an excel file.

With that said, however, the generic python data structure could easily be stored as an excel file. Here are [three save functions](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.5/capability.html#export-data-from-python) at module level: save_as and save_book_as. Here is an example on [how to save an array into an xls file](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.5/tutorial_data_conversion.html#save-an-array-to-an-excel-sheet).

Comparing with pandas, **pyexcel** is a light-weight, easy-to-install, simple-to-understand and component-based excel data processing package. However, it does not aim to replace pandas but to provide an alternative to data analysis tasks that **are less complex**.

Comparing with openpyxl and xlsxwriter, **pyexcel** lets you focus on data, instead of file formats, where you could reuse your code to handle ods, xls and csv file formats **without code changes**.

Comment: another legendary answer from chfw :)